# Why are the 2 outputs different?

Tags: c

I am writing to a char array but when I print I get 2 different outputs. I know this is a lot of code, but if you can - please try to maybe catch why I'm getting a different output every time... First code:

```
int len = strlen(oldStr);
int i = 0;
char c;

while (i < len - 1)
{
    c = *(oldStr + i);

    if (isSpace(c)) {
        c = *(oldStr + i + 1);

        if (!isSpace(c)) { 
            *(newStr + i) = '\0';
            printf(" ");
        }
    } else {
        *(newStr + i) = c;
        printf("%c", *(newStr + i));
    }

    i++;
}
*(newStr + i) = '\0';
*(newStr + i + 1) = '\0';
```

When I'm printing here, it prints the whole string list just like it should.

But then, when I use this to print:

```
for (i = 0; !(*(newStr + i) == '\0' && *(newStr + i + 1) == '\0'); i++) {
    if (*(newStr + i) == '\0')
        printf(" ");
    else
        printf("%c", *(newStr + i));
}
```

It only prints part of the string.

For example: `"One two three four\n\tfive six"`
The first code prints `"One two three four five six"`
The second code prints `"One two three"`

Why?

Comment: Can you ask yourself what someone looking at the code you have provided would have to do to that code to create a program that produces the output you are seeing, and then actually produce that program?

Comment: Where did you declared `*newStr`?

Comment: It was given to me as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have in your input text two consecutive isspace()'s like `\n` followed by a `\t`, you don't enter anything in newStr[], but incrementing `i`. This gives you one uninitialized character in newStr[].